# What's jQuery's css syntax for addition and subtraction on numerical values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm certain I've seen this before. This is how i remember it

`$cnta.css({ top:'+=50' });`

Needless to say, it doesn't work :-)

I know i can parse the css value, manipulate the result and put it back into css, but that takes twice the code.

---

**Thanks for answers!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That works for `.animate()`:

```
$cnta.animate({ top:'+=50' }, 0);
```

For `.css()`, you can pass a function that will do the addition for you:

<s>$cnta.css('top', function(i,current) { return parseInt(current) + 50; });</s>

```
$cnta.css('top', function(i,current) { return (parseInt(current) + 50 || 50); });​
```

---

**EDIT:** Changed the animation from `1` to `0`. As **@Nick Craver** noted, a `0` animation will work.

**EDIT:** Gave a better answer for the `.css()` version. If the `top` has not been given any value yet, then doing `.parseInt(current)` will return `NaN`. Updated to correct it.

Comment: +1 - You can pass a `0` to animate as well, which eliminates a lot of overhead associated with a 1ms animation ;)